# Why is there a difference in giving values to global javascript objects locally?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, javascript-objects, local-variables

Please explain why changing a global objects string property in local scope does affect the property in a global scope but giving a new value to the whole object doesn't.

In my example, the first time I run changeMyName function, I get what I'm expecting - a change in my_global_object.name value.

But why doesn't the second time I run the function change the my_global_object object to my_global_object.children.first_child object?

```
var my_global_object=new Object();
my_global_object.name='my parent name'
my_global_object.children=new Object();
my_global_object.children.first_child=new Object();
my_global_object.children.first_child.name='my first child name';

function changeMyName(child_name,new_name){
    var my_local_object;
    my_local_object=my_global_object;
    if(child_name) my_local_object=my_local_object.children[child_name];
    my_local_object.name=new_name;  
}

changeMyName(false,'new parent name'); 

changeMyName('first_child','new first child name');
```

Why is this "=" assignment

```
if(child_name) my_local_object=my_local_object.children[child_name];
```

different from this "=" ?

```
my_local_object.name=new_name;
```

Is there a some sort of a "giving a value" and "passing a refrence" difference?

Comment: Please explain your first line . Where did you change the global object in your code ?

Comment: Inside the changeMyName function I assing the global object to the local object and change the value of it's name property. If I log the my_global_object after that, it has the name I've passed on to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 my_local_object=my_global_object;
```

Assigning the reference of the object referred by variable `my_global_object` to the variable `my_local_object` here . So now both variables refer to the same object .

```
my_local_object.name=new_name;
```

Updating the `name` property of the object , which is referenced by both variables `my_global_object` and `my_local_object` , hence `my_global_object.name` will be same as `my_local_object.name`.

```
my_local_object=my_local_object.children[child_name];
```

Assigning the variable `my_local_object` reference to the object referred to by `my_local_object.children[child_name]` . So now `my_local_object` variable doesn't point to the object referred by `my_global_object`  variable .